# TYPO3 use several content elements

Tags: typo3

new to TYPO3. Trying to learn.

Let's say i have about 10 content elements on my page. I will add them to the "page" list in the backend UI.

How do i actually use them via Typoscript when using fluid?

I have one content element named "logoTitle" and one content element named "content". Both in the "normal" column.

How can i access them via Typoscript?

I tried something like that:

```
content < styles.content.get #only get the "content" one from the normal column
logoTitle < styles.content.get #only get the "logoTitle" one from the normal column
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In very general there are 4 default columns in TYPO3: `normal, left, right, border`, so you can put your elements into separate columns (let's say `content` into `normal` and `logoTitle` into `border`, then your TS should look like:

```
content < styles.content.get
logoTitle < styles.content.getBorder
```

**Edit**:

For more columns/mapped elements you have at least 4 possibilities:

1. EXT: gridelements
2. EXT: TemplaVoila
3. adding new columns into your page: http://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/35/
4. Finally as **Jost** pointed in his comment in TYPO3 ver. 6+ you can use Backend Layouts for adding more columns, which are considered as a raw replacement of the old way pointed in previous point.

Personally I prefer them in this order, as first two options allows to keep the BE clean, anyway 3rd is most *traditional* - for rendering new columns into check `colPos` keyword in the docs.

Comment: Well i already know that. The problem is that we have MORE than 4 actual content Elements to put in. There are only 4 colums so we have to put more than one content element into one column. How do we seperate them later?

Comment: you didn't mention that you need more than 4 columns... anyway check my answer

Comment: Then maybe im doing something wrong. Im currently trying to map a given finished html/css design with fluid. I am trying to replace every instance of text in the "lorem ipsum dolor" template with {id1}, {id2} etc. to let the backend user define the content via a lot of content elements. Is that wrong? Anyway thanks for your answer!

Comment: There is another, built-in way to add more columns: Use backend layouts. You can create them as records in the list module and edit them using a wizard (or plain typoscript). Then you can define the backend layout to use for a page and its subpages in the appearance-tab of the page properties.

Comment: @Jost: So in generell our way of thinking is correct?

Comment: Ach, @Jost you're absolutely right, actually in TYPO3 6.x BE layouts are considered as a raw replacement of the  old way pointed as 3 option :S my bad ;)

Comment: @eikwood I'm not sure about what you are really doing (would have to see the template and implementation), but usually there is some stuff that is not changed by the editor (e.g. logo or company title). I'd hardcode that stuff into the template, or make typoscript constants from it. Then there is stuff that is a property of each page, like page title, navigation title, subtitle, meta-keywords, meta-description and so on, which will be changed by editors. That should come directly from the page record. And finally, there is content, which is read from columns.